# Blender 2.9 - UV Unwrap not appearing

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm really new to the program, and it may be that I'm just being stupid. I'm trying to make some pants for The Sims 4, and they're done and all that, now I just need to add texture - but when I click "Unwrap" (and yes I selected everything), nothing will appear in the UV window. I'm really confused. I've looked up several tutorials but none of them are helping because they're really complicated.

I've got the file here if anyone wants to take a look.

It'd be super appreciated if anyone helped me out, I've been ripping my hair out about this for a day now.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L7HIfVexjJ3oocXDLqGHoGNrSLR3cJbG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You've opened the *Image Editor*, not the *UV Editor*. If you want to see the UV in *Image Editor*, switch it to *Paint* mode, but you won't be able to edit the UV in this editor:

[image]

You probably want the *UV Editor*:

[image]